# find parent nodes in a tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, yield

I created a JSON example and I would like to input an id and get that item and all parents.
Though my code does work, it doesn't feel pythonic, there must be a better way.

```
a_list = [
    {
        "name": {"en": "Canada"},
        "id": "CAN",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": {"en": "British Columbia"},
                "id": "01",
                "children": [
                    {"name": {"en": "Vancouver"}, "id": "10", "children": []},
                    {"name": {"en": "Victoria"}, "id": "11", "children": []}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": {"en": "Nova Scotia"},
                "id": "02",
                "children": [
                    {"name": {"en": "Halifax"}, "id": "13", "children": []}
                ]
            }
        ],
        "name": {"en": "USA"},
        "id": "US",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": {"en": "Virgina"},
                "id": "VA",
                "children": [
                    {"name": {"en": "Richmond"}, "id": "20", "children": []},
                    {"name": {"en": "Norfolk"}, "id": "21", "children": []}
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": {"en": "Maryland"},
                "id": "MD",
                "children": [
                    {"name": {"en": "Baltimore"}, "id": "23", "children": []},
                    {"name": {"en": "Gaithersburg"}, "id": "24", "children": []}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

so I created this function

```
def find_item_and_parents_in_list(value, items):
    item_found = []
    for item in items:
        if item['id'] == value:
            item_found.append(item)
        else:
            item_list = find_item_and_parents_in_list(value, item['children'])
            if item_list:
                item_list.append(item)
                item_found = item_list

    return item_found
```

if I use it, i.e

```
items = find_item_in_list("23", a_list)
for item in items:
   print(item['id'])
```

it returns
23
MD
US

but can my find_item_and_parents_in_list be written in a better way? using yield for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def get_paths(d, _id, c = []):
   if d['id'] == _id:
      yield c+[_id]
   yield from [i for b in d['children'] for i in get_paths(b, _id, c+[d['id']])]

print(list(get_paths(a_list[0], '23'))[0])
```

Output:

```
['US', 'MD', '23']
```